# Trouble accessing values of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array in JavaScript that I receive from the back end and has the following structure:

```
scope.myArray = [{"0":[1,2,3,4],"1":[0,2,3,1,4]},{"0":[1,2,3,4],"1":[0,2,3,1,4]}]
```

I tried to retrieve some of the values by doing this:

```
for(var x=0;x<scope.myArray.length;x++){
    console.log("myArray is ....... " + JSON.stringify(scope.myArray[x].0))
}
```

and this

```
 for(var x=0;x<scope.myArray.length;x++){
    console.log("myArray is ....... " + JSON.stringify(scope.myArray[x]."0"))
}
```

but neither works.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use: `JSON.stringify(scope.myArray[x]["0"]))` or just `[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), like this

```js
var myArray = [{"0":[1,2,3,4],"1":[0,2,3,1,4]},{"0":[1,2,3,4],"1":[0,2,3,1,4]}]

for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    console.log("myArray is ....... " + JSON.stringify(myArray[x][0]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should access the properties via bracket notation.

```
for (var x=0; x < scope.myArray.length; x++){
    console.log("myArray is ....... " + JSON.stringify(scope.myArray[x]['0']))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created an array containing one object, with keys "0", "1", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
scope.myArray = [
    {
        "0": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "1": [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]
    }, 
    {
        "3": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "4": [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]
    }
];
scope.myArray.forEach(function(item){
     console.log("myArray is ....... " + JSON.stringify(item[0]))
 });
```